# Using McAfee Web Gateway 6.8.7 to log all web traffic

Tags: logging

How can I use McAfee Web Gateway 6.8.7 to keep a log of all the websites accessed that go through the filter?  I'm only concerned with Http and Https, and only concerned with the URL name, not the actual content of the page.

Is this the right SE forum for this question?

Comment: This might be more appropriate at [sf].  If you'd like the question migrated, you can flag it for one of the moderators to handle.

Answer (score 0):

this requires only firewall rule on windows platform 
try to search on inbound rules and outbound rules with windows firewall

Comment: I'm running a huge WAN, not just one computer